# Issue with 'use client' in Next js 13.5.1 still getting response in server side

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, antd, next.js13

I am using 'use client' in latest version of next js 13.5.3 but component is still render from server side and also difficult to use tailwind and antd both together in next js

Anyone know about this issue So, pleas help me out

Answer (score 2):

React client components with the `"use client"` directive will be rendered client-side but Next.js hydrates client components on the server side which is called SSR.

That means every client component will be executed first on the server.

### Opt-out

#### Put your client code with an effect hook like `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("this should only be logged in the browser console")
}, [])
```

#### Disable SSR for the component by dynamic import

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
const ClientComponent = dynamic(import("path/to/component.tsx"), { ssr: false })
```