Navbar implementation in Next - Detect current page
I'm currently attempting to implement a global navbar in Next that detects the current page to highlight that link. Below is the current implementation:
<Link href="/about" className={`${window.location.href.contains('/about') ? 'text-red-500 cursor-default' : 'link-underline'} mx-2`}>About</Link>

Unfortunately, this throws a "window is not defined" ReferenceError. I'm assuming Next is rendering this server-side so window can't be accessed, how can I read the current URL inline like this? (Or, am I going about this the wrong way)

Add “use client” in the top of the file

Even with "use client", you'll get the same error. Add typeof window !== "undefined" && window.location.... More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201618/18079514

You can use usePathname to read the current URL's pathname.
'use client'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

export const Component: React.FC = () => {
    const pathName = usePathname()

    const isOnAboutPage = pathName === '/about'
    const isOnHomePage = pathName === '/'

    ...
}

