ReferenceError: document is not defined in nextjs useing typescript
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at m (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/(routes)/about_us/page.js:1:4079)
at nM (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
at nL (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
at nI (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
at nM (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47570)
at nM (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
at nL (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
at nB (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
at nF (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
at nL (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
Error occurred prerendering page "/about_us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
It appear error that page on layout file not found like this
Error occurred prerendering page "/about_us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/cart/check_out". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/cart". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/contact". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/products". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
also it work good on localhost but when build on my pc  appear error
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200502/issue-with-use-client-in-next-js-13-5-1-still-getting-response-in-server-side/77201618#77201618

sounds like you might be using server-side rendering if document is not defined. You can either stick "use client" at the top of the files where you need it to opt into client side rendering - what exactly are you using it for?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
